# Groupby with aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
AAA_cost = (
    AAA_v2[['total_cost','cost_per_yr']]
    .reset_index()
    .groupby(['member_key','cost_per_yr'])
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
    .pivot(index='member_key', columns='cost_per_yr', values='total_cost')
    .fillna(0)
)
```

I keep getting error when doing groupby..not sure why? Can anyone help figure this out?

```
KeyError: 'member_key'
----> 1 AAA_cost = AAA_v2[['total_cost','cost_per_yr']].reset_index().groupby(['member_key','cost_per_yr']
```

Comment: Hi, KeyError Usually refer to column not found. Could you please check in 'member_key' is present as column. Python is case sensitive so please make sure that's now the case

Comment: `AAA_v2[['total_cost','cost_per_yr']]` selects only those two columns from `AAA_v2`. 'member_key' is not among them.